# check if a bib environment is defined

Tags: biblatex, conditionals

I am using the `\defbibenvironment` command for code like this

```
\defbibenvironment{numbered+bold}{...}
```

which is later used in

```
\printbibliography[env=numbered+bold, heading=none, resetnumbers=true]
```

However if the first is not defined, the `\printbibliography` fails.

I want the code to be fail-save and therefore check if the environment is defined. That means I am looking for something like

```
\IfElseBibEnvironmentDefined{numbered+bold}
{\printbibliography[env=numbered+bold, heading=none, resetnumbers=true]}
{Error: environment numbered+bold not defined}
```

The question is how to check for this environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\defbibenvironment{foo}` defines a macro called

```
\blx@env@foo
```

So you can do

```
\ifcsdef{blx@env@numbered+bold}
  {\printbibliography[env=numbered+bold, heading=none, resetnumbers=true]}
  {Error: environment numbered+bold not defined}
```

Of course you can define a macro:

```
\newcommand{\IfDefinedBibEnvironment}[1]{\ifcsdef{blx@env@#1}}
```

and then you can do the above with

```
\IfDefinedBibEnvironment{numbered+bold}
  {\printbibliography[env=numbered+bold, heading=none, resetnumbers=true]}
  {Error: environment numbered+bold not defined}
```